# for method comparison studies do we ever use randomisation, period effects and washout periods?

Tags: method-comparison, bland-altman-plot

By method comparison I mean we have a number of "individuals" and for each a quantity eg blood pressure is measured by 2 measuring devices. So we have a pair of measures for each person 1 from each device. We wants to know if the 2 devices "agree" ie give similar measures on each person maybe so we can replace an existing device by a newer (cheaper ?) one.

Often we might use Bland Altman and calculate limits of agreement for our paired data and then assess if those LoAs lie within some maximum tolerated range of clinical equivalence.

This question may apply more to measuring on live people (as opposed to comparing 2 assays on stored samples) but do we ever randomise the order in which the 2 devices measure each person. Or have period effects in some analysis ? Or have a wash out period in case the first measurement has some effect (raises pulse or blood pressure). These are cross-over trial concepts of course.